# How to introduce delay in POSTGRESQL 9.3 replication?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-9.3

I have master slave replication setup. How I can force some delay in replication ?

Is there a setting that I can use ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Not in 9.3.

In 9.4 you can use `min_recovery_apply_delay`. See [this blog post](http://www.depesz.com/2013/12/20/waiting-for-9-4-allow-time-delayed-standbys-and-recovery/).

In 9.3, if you have WAL-archive based replication (no streaming) you could archive the WAL to one location, and only move it to a location readable by the standby after a delay. You can't do it with streaming in 9.3.